# How to define a has_many scope based on multiple conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `has_many` association and I am looking to pull only the associated records that have an ID of a particular value, and only if one condition is true.

For example:

```
class Account
   has_many :issues
   has_many :nodes, through: :issues
end
```

```
class Issue
   belongs_to :account
   has_many :nodes, dependent: :destroy, # where node.account_id == [1,2,3,5] if self.account.trial_account
end
```

```
class Node
   belongs_to :account
   belongs_to :issue
end
```

So basically, if the account is a trial account, then `issue.nodes` would only return back 4 records.

Comment: what should happen if `if self.account.trial_account` is false? should the association not be on these ids only?

Comment: Exactly it should include all if the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a different method on Issue:

```rb
class Issue 
  ...
  
  def effective_nodes # or visible_nodes or so
    if account.trial_account?
      nodes
    else 
      nodes.limit(4) # or your static nodes
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide some kind of lambda to your association definition.
Something like this:

```rb
has_many :nodes, -> (issue) do
  where(account_id: [1,2,3,5]) if issue.account.trial_account
end
```

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but from the code base I see that the node belongs to account AND issue.

Using this code block from my example will return nodes that belongs to the requested issue **AND** belongs to account with id 1,2,3 or 5.

If you need to get any nodes that just belongs to account with id 1,2,3 or 5, I think the better approach will be to stick with @stwienert solution, defining a method that returns the correct nodes.